# How to retain indentation format when selecting from history in IPython

Tags: ipython

[image: messed up indentation]

**[17]** was hand-typed while **[18]** was retrieved from history with an up arrow key press. The latter is still executable but I wonder if there's any way of keeping indentation format intact under this situation.

Comment: Not in the terminal. If you use the Qt console, it should behave better.

Comment: Indentation is intact. That's why it still executes. Why do you want it indented more?

Comment: @WilliamDenman but if any changes to the code, generally it raises exception because of indentation